# How to convert BigInteger to scientific notation

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I am currently writing some code for a simple calculator, and I wanted to add on a factorial function to it.

Since the numbers can get quite big, I used BigIntegers for the factorials. However, when I work out the factorial of, let's say 35, I get the answer, but is like 50 or so digits long. Is there a way to convert that number to something like: 
1.03 x 10^40 ?

here is what the code looks like for the factorial:

```
public static BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger numberEntered) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    for (long i = 2; i <= numberEntered; i++) {
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: [How to convert BigInteger number into scientific notation string and again reconvert that string into BigInteger in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38534460)

Comment: The point of using `BigInteger` is to get all the digits, otherwise a `double` is much more efficient.

Comment: I tried using `long`, `int` and `double`, however, when working out anything larger than 20 factorial, the answer is wrong. Only BigInteger works right now, but it just leaves such a long number that is not readable.. :/

Comment: A double can hold the result of 20! with ease. It is even capable to get up to 170!. You must have made a mistake doing the calculation.

Comment: Also @Johnny Mopp, that doesn't seem to work for some reason.  :/

Comment: @Henry Omg, I found the mistake, the return type was wrong lol. Thank you for the help! and thank you to those that posted answers too! ^^